# auto Login to site have token with PHP cURL

Tags: php, authentication, curl, token

I want to write a login script to my account that will directly login to my account and then give a link in my dashboard, which is a link conversion site, and convert the link.
I was able to inspect the method, which is sent by post method
And I find the parameters that are email, password and submit button and send it with the curl PHP command, but when echoing the result, curl does not show anything and then when I looked, I see that it creates a token after the post method of the site and right after that. Sending postal values, it will also be sent quickly
Can someone help me login, this is my first project in this field

A token is something like this that changes every time

/account.php?token=1659800372_382099

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question,  and also take the [tour] and read [ask], (as the system already recommended you to do before posting anything) and then try again. Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear if you're describing your own code or the behaviour of a site you want to imitate. If this is your own code, you need to show enough of it to form a [mre] of the issue you're having, and also give a clearer description of the specific problem.